# User logged in stackoverflow.com, then how the askubuntu.com know this, and let user log in?

Tags: security, cookies, cross-domain, jsonp, single-sign-on

I logged in stackoverflow.com and then I click a link, which nav me to askubuntu.com. I find I also logged in askubuntu.com. but those are two different domains and cannot share cookie.

so, how askubuntu.com know a user is logged in stackoeverflow.com ?

Answer (score 2):

askubuntu and stackoverflow both use the StackExchange login. Your stackoverflow account can also log you into all other StackExchange websites. So since you logged into stackoverflow, you are automatically logged into askubuntu at the same time, and all other StackExchange websites. Go to https://stackexchange.com/sites to see all the stackexchange websites there are. Hope this helps!